# Format TimeSpan to mm:ss for positive and negative TimeSpans

Tags: c#, time, formatting, string-formatting

I'm looking for a solution in .net 3.5 I wrote the following working solution:

```
private string FormatTimeSpan(TimeSpan time)
{
    return String.Format("{0}{1:00}:{2:00}", time < TimeSpan.Zero ? "-" : "", Math.Abs(time.Minutes), Math.Abs(time.Seconds));
}
```

But my Question is: Is there a better way? Maybe something shorter where I do not need an helper function.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Somewhat shorter, using [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx):

```
private string FormatTimeSpan(TimeSpan time)
{
    return ((time < TimeSpan.Zero) ? "-" : "") + time.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the negative sign appear automatically from the time.ToString() ?

Comment: @Tisho - It doesn't, not with a custom format string. And there is no custom format specifier for it.

Comment: I'm nur sure but does time.ToString(@"mm\:ss") work for .net 3.5?

Comment: Just got the idea to implement it as Extension that will make the functionality available all over my program.

Comment: @Tarion: @"mm\:ss" doesn't work for me either. Returns always "00:00". Someone a clue?

Answer (score 2):

for below .Net 4.0

You can use:

```
get { return Time.ToString().Substring(3); }
```

Comment: I think this is a smart hack.

Comment: I'd recommend against this approach, as it relies on the default `ToSring` behavior, which is Culture dependent.