# Timespan in milliseconds to minutes and seconds only

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I have a Timespan that is always in milliseconds, but I need to show the date in minutes and seconds only so that it's always `"mm:ss"`. Even if there are hours in the timespan, the output string should contain only minutes and seconds.

For example, if there is a timespan of `02:40:30`, it should get converted to `160:30`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Is the input is Timespan type or string?

Comment: Consider doing this by hand.  Given a certain number of milliseconds, could you convert it into minutes and seconds using basic math?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11024365/4660897?

Comment: How the `30` seconds in the input becomes `20` in output?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Reed's answer is ALMOST correct, but not quite. For example, if timespan is 00:01:59, Reed's solution outputs "2:59" due to rounding by the `F0` numeric format. Here's the correct implementation:

```
string output = string.Format("{0}:{1:00}", 
        (int)timespan.TotalMinutes, // <== Note the casting to int.
        timespan.Seconds);
```

In C# 6, you can use string interpolation to reduce code:

```
var output = $"{(int)timespan.TotalMinutes}:{timespan.Seconds:00}";
```

Comment: Thank you. I noticed the extra minute in my testing as well.

Comment: @Diego Note, that if timespan has non-zero milliseconds they will be discarded. So if your timespan is 1h 59s and 999ms it will be output as "1:59" and not as "2:00".

Comment: what about timespan.ToString("mm\\:ss");

Answer (score 6):

I do it this way

```
timespan.ToString("mm\\:ss");
```

Comment: 61 minutes will show up as "01:00" - whoops!

Answer (score 5):

You can format this yourself using the [standard numeric format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string output = string.Format("{0}:{1}", (int)timespan.TotalMinutes, timespan.Seconds);
```

Comment: Diego is correct in that the TotalMinutes rounds it to the nearest minute which ended up being an extra minute.

Answer (score 1):

That is a pretty basic math problem.

Divide by 1000 to get total number of seconds.

Divide by 60 to get number of minutes.
Total seconds - (minutes * 60) = remaining seconds.

Comment: I know. I did that but I wanted to see if there was a more straightforward way.